# Catching called method belongs to which class

Tags: java, overriding

My query is suppose we have number of classes suppose three classes are there like this:

**See my updated query. That is the case they have asked for.**

```
class MethodContainerA {
    public void display() {
        System.out.println("Display from MethodContainerA");
    }
}

class MethodContainerB extends MethodContainerA {
    public void display() {
        System.out.println("Display from MethodContainerB");
    }
}

class MethodContainerC extends MethodContainerB {

}

public class MethodCallRecognization {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MethodContainerC methodContainerC = new MethodContainerC();
        methodContainerC.display();

            // I want to know here
    }
}
```

My question is that after calling can I get the information `display()` method is called from which class. Note, this question is not for debugging purposes - it is theoretical.

Comment: *Why* do you need to know? That's a design smell in itself.

Comment: Well, you get the information printed to your console, or am I misunderstanding something? What would you do with that information?

Comment: So do you mean in MethodContainerC.display you want it to know that it was called from MethodCallRecognization? Or what?

Comment: After the call & return?  No.

Comment: @slhck I am not asking for debugging purpose

Comment: why are u asking? there is no point to it

Comment: @Mr D I was asked to do that by my company thats why.

Comment: @MrD Many questions are theoretical. This one happens to be slightly basic. Can we accept this fact and move on? If you don't like the question, downvote it

Comment: @HotLicks I was not allowed to do that.

Comment: @Nikhil quit they're idiots

Comment: @Mr D but there may be some way I have to recognize I want the class name from it was called suppose 3rd class do not have that mehtod then.

Comment: @all everybody is misunderstanding my question. Please I know how overiding works but read carefully. I don't have objection on downvoting if I am wrong but please understand it carefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
public class MethodCallRecognization {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    MethodContainerC methodContainerC = new MethodContainerC();
    methodContainerC.display();
    // I want to know here
    String className=getClassName(methodContainerC.getClass(), "display") ;
    System.out.println(className);
  }
  public static String getClassName(Class c,String methodName){
       Method m[]=c.getDeclaredMethods();
       for(Method m1:m){
        if(m1.getName().equals(methodName)){
            return c.getName();
        }
       }
       return getClassName(c.getSuperclass(),methodName);

  }
}
```

If methods are overloaded you also want to check with Argument Types instead of names. but this should give you idea.

As per comment here is better version of `getClassName`

```
public static String getClassname(Class c, String methodName){
 try{
  Method m= c.getDeclaredMethod( methodName);
  return c.getName();
}catch(NoSuchMethodException  nse){
   return getClassName(c.getSuperclass(),methodName);
}
}
```

If dsiplay Method is taking Parameter then

```
 public class MethodCallRecognization {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        MethodContainerC methodContainerC = new MethodContainerC();
        methodContainerC.display("" , "");//Suppose it takes String id and String name parameter 
        // I want to know here
         Class[] parametertype={String.class,String.class};
        String className=getClassName(methodContainerC.getClass(), "display", parametertype) ;
        System.out.println(className);
      }
      public static String getClassname(Class c, String methodName, Class[] parametertype){
        try{
           Method m= c.getDeclaredMethod( methodName, parametertype);
           return c.getName();
        }catch(NoSuchMethodException  nse){
          return getClassName(c.getSuperclass(),methodName, parametertype);
       }
      }
    }
```

Comment: You can (supposedly) do getDeclaredMethod to get just the one Method object by name.

Comment: (It is a little messy to set up the parms, however.)

Comment: I will add param example too in few minutes

Comment: @rahul Maindargi Nice answer +1 for you.

Answer (score 3):

Well, actually there probably is a way to do this (haven't tried):

Get the Class of the instance used.  Do getDeclaredMethod to get the Method.  Do getDeclaringClass on the Method.

Comment: already gave the answer  with code just before your Answer :).

Comment: @Hot Licks that is what people started downvoting. I am explaining the situation.

Comment: @Nikhil - Do note that this technique has nothing to do with whether you "just called" the method or not -- you just need the instance pointer and there need not be a call on that pointer anywhere in the entire app.

Answer (score 1):

You will be calling `display()` from `MethodContainerC`, and will thus print out `Display from MethodContainerC`.

This is the way overriding works: If you want to call the superclass's method, you need to explicitly invoke `super` from within the overridden method. Otherwise, you'll be calling the overridden method.

However, if you do not have a method `display()` in `MethodContainerC`, you will instead invoke `MethodContainerB`'s display method. This is because inheritance follows the closest path:

- `MethodContianerA` has a method `display()`...
- which is overridden by `MethodContainerB`...
- (which is overridden by `MethodContianerC`.)

If you cut out the last step, `MethodContainerB` still overrides `display()` for all `MethodContainerC`. The closest implementation of the method will always be run.

Comment: @if display is not written in MethodContainerC then.

Comment: @Nikhil - If there is no `display` method in MethodContainerC then the nearest superclass implementation of `display` will be invoked.

Comment: Then you will be calling it's nearest super class's method and it will print `Display from MethodContainerB`

Comment: @GnomezGrave That is I want to know which is the nearest class.